# What does a Shift left (<<) do?

Tags: apex

As fas I as know the shift left (<<), will remove the high level bits and and zeros in the low level bits, for example:

```
255 << 1 // (Decimal: 255 --> Binary: 11111111)
```

- 11111110 (Expected result)
- 111111110 (Actual result)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are assuming that the bitwise operator is always working on an 8 bit number... a 1 bit shift left on 255 will give you 510 as long as you are not costrained to an 8 bit integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers are 32-bit (signed) 2's Complement in Salesforce, with no option to choose any other representation. We can infer this is the case by looking at [the documentation on primitive data types in apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm).

The relevant excerpt:

> Integer:  A 32-bit number that does not include a decimal point. Integers have a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647

If it were a signed 1's complement, the absolute value of the min and max integers would be the same.

So, `255` is:

`00000000000000000000000011111111`

Shift left once, and you get:

`00000000000000000000000111111110`

To accomplish what you're looking to do, you'll need to additionally bitwise-and with 255 (e.g. `(255 << 1) & 255`) to mask-out the higher-order bits that you want to discard.

```
00000000000000000000000111111110
&
00000000000000000000000011111111
=
00000000000000000000000011111110
```

Comment: This also works: (255 >> 1) <<  1

Comment: I wish I knew of a practical purpose for this. Never had the need to use it nor seen it used....I know there is or it would not be part of the library. But I digress....Nice answer

Comment: @Eric I can't speak to bit-shifting, but I have used bitwise-and as well as bitwise-or to find the first and last IP address in a given subnet (ip address & subnet mask = first address of subnet, ip address | !subnet mask = last address of subnet)...but that's about the only practical use I've had for bitwise operations. I maintain that 99% of the time, if you think you need to use bit operators, you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: @DerekF That's kind of silly. Bit operators are tools to be used correctly. If you're trying to use bit operators on everything, then it's probably being used wrong. 100% of the time I've used bit operators, I needed to use bit operators.